# Fluent Assertions OnlyContain

Tags: fluent-assertions

Using FluentAssertions, I want to check a list only contains objects with certain values.

For example, I attempted to use a lambda;

```
myobject.Should().OnlyContain(x=>x.SomeProperty == "SomeValue");
```

However, this syntax is not allowed.

Comment: I found a way of achieving this but not sure if there is a better way;     myobject.Select(x=>x.SomeProperty ).Should().Equal("SomeValue")

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure that should work. Check out [this example](https://github.com/fluentassertions/fluentassertions/blob/3.4.1/FluentAssertions.Shared.Specs/GenericCollectionAssertionsSpecs.cs#L234) unit test from FluentAssertions' GitHub repository:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void When_a_collection_contains_items_not_matching_a_predicate_it_should_throw()
    {
        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Arrange
        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        IEnumerable<int> collection = new[] { 2, 12, 3, 11, 2 };

        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Act
        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Action act = () => collection.Should().OnlyContain(i => i <= 10, "10 is the maximum");

        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Act
        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        act.ShouldThrow<AssertFailedException>().WithMessage(
            "Expected collection to contain only items matching (i <= 10) because 10 is the maximum, but {12, 11} do(es) not match.");
    }
```